# My account has been banned after 3 questions, where only 1 question has negative votes

Tags: discussion, support

> You've asked 3 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community.

I've asked 3 questions, 2 questions with 0 votes, the 3rd with `-4`.

Is it really enough to get the ban? How long does it stand?

What's the easiest way to get over the limit? Post more answers or it's just time-based?

Answer (score 15):

> Is it really enough to get the ban?

Just FYI, in the course of an hour you asked questions which have as their votes (as I type this):

> -6 / +1 / 3 close votes
>
> -2 / +2 / 2 close votes
>
> -0 / +0 / 2 close votes

That's generally not a good trend. For more reading, I'd suggest the [main meta post on this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/193412).

Also worth noting that [this warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work) still exists:

[image: The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed]

You ignored it and posted the question anyway...

Answer (score 5):

It's not all about votes.

Each of your 3 questions has *also* attracted close votes. As I look at them, two have 2 close votes, and the other has 3.

While I don't know the exact formula for the threshold at which you get a question ban, that'll come into it.

As to the length of the ban, the message you get when you try to post a question should tell you - it's not public data, so only you or the SE team will be able to find that out.